# Время и часовой пояс в PHP и MySQL

Tags: дата, php

Всем привет! У меня возникла проблема со временем. Причём не на 1, а сразу на нескольких хостингах. Суть проблемы такова:

Есть у меня в таблице **table** поле ***datetime***, ну мы туда записываем текущую дату и всё ок. Время правильное.
А вот когда я хочу её вывести в нужном для меня формате, то использую функции **date** и **strtotime**. Вот так:

```
$human-date-time = date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($sql_result['datetime']));
```

И вот в переменной $human-date-time время на час позже чем записано в базе.
Локальное время правильное. Часовой пояс в ПХП стоит **Europe/Moscow**.

Как сделать(желательно через .htaccess) чтобы время было нормальное? Повторюсь, такое на нескольких хостингах и на моей локальной машине.

P.S если поставить зону **Europe/London** то всё ок. Время правильное

Comment: Поле с названием `datetime` — какого типа: `TIMESTAMP` или `DATETIME`?

Comment: DATETIME

Причём если просто использовать date("H:i"); то время правильное, а при зоне Europe/London уже лондонское. Проблема только с MySQL

Comment: @jeid, в datetime используется время без конвертирования, насколько я знаю. Значит такое время занесли.

Comment: Нашел вот что, т.к для работы с базой я использую phpactiverecord то  по умолчанию дата там выводится в формате DateTime::RFC2822. Поэтому возвращает результат в таком виде: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 14:33:40 +0300
после чего если воткнуть сюда date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($sql_result['datetime'])); то время будет уже 15:33.

А вот если использовать другой формат, обычный Y-d-m H:is то тогда всё нормально. Вообщем-то вопрос можно считать закрытым, т.к просто поменяю формат по умолчанию. Но всё равно было бы интересно узнать почему ПХП так странно преобразует время.